# Differential equation simplification of the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Normally, how I solve DE is that I go to one of the last steps of any method and I don't simplify the solution if unnecessary. However, this time this simplification is necessary. What I mean I need to get to the point where the solution would look like 
 
 y(t)=... (something)

The differential equation I am interested in:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = (y-1)(y-2) $

I will give a shorted version of steps because what I'm interested, hopefully, you too, is at the end. When it comes to the solution. 
 
 
$ \int \frac{1}{(y-2)(y-1)}dy = \int t  dt$

$ -3 ln|y-2|+3ln|y-1|=t$

 
 I simplified it 
 
 
$ ln |\frac{(y-1)^3}{(y-2)^3}|=t$ 
 
 equation to the power of exponential

$ \frac{(y-1)^3}{(y-2)^3}=e^t$ 
 
 
and that's the point where I am stuck. How to get from this point to y=...(something). If you are interested please comment.

Comment: $\frac{(y-1)}{(y-2)}=e^{t/3}$ should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-3 \ln|y-2|+3\ln|y-1|=t+k$$
Divide by 3 both sides:
$$\ln|\dfrac {y-1}{y-2}|= \frac t3+c_1$$
$$\dfrac {y-1}{y-2}=ce^{  t/3} \implies {y-1}=(y-2)ce^{ t/3}$$
$$
 y(1-ce^{  t/3})=1-2ce^{  t/3}$$
Then deduce the value of $y(t)$....
$$ y(t)= \dfrac {1-2ce^{  t/3}}{1-ce^{  t/3}}$$

---

But you made a mistake with the fraction decomposition:
$$ \dfrac 1 {(y-2)(y-1)} =\dfrac 1{y-2}-\dfrac 1 {y-1}$$
$$ \int \dfrac {dy} {(y-2)(y-1)} =\ln |{y-2}|-\ln |{y-1}|+C$$
So that we have:
$$\ln|\dfrac {y-2}{y-1}|=t+k$$
$$\dfrac {y-2}{y-1}=ce^t \implies y(t)=\dfrac {2-ce^t}{1-ce^t}$$